# Trying to check both null and empty value in one go and shortest way

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to check null or empty value in mvc view side in shortest way  in one go but not able to achieve null.

i have value coming from controller in array and in view side i'm checking null or empty

controller

```
object o3 = ds.Tables[6].Rows[0]["pm"];
                if (o3 != null)
                {
                    string val = o3.ToString();
                    string[] values3 = val.Split('~');
                    ViewBag.values3 = values3;
                }
```

View side

```
<td>@(values3[0].IsEmpty()?0:Convert.ToInt32(values3[0]))</td>
```

Expected:Both null and empty value should be cheked in one go and 0 should be output if value is null or emty.
Actual:Able to check only empty value.
Any idea how to check both null and empty value in shortest way would be appreciated.

Comment: what about `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` ?

Comment: @Aarif how to apply here @(values3[0].IsEmpty()?0:Convert.ToInt32(values3[0])

Comment: did you try this `@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(values3[0])?0:Convert.ToInt32(values3[0])` ?

Comment: @Aarif thanks it's working